# Moving Delete button in Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard

On most laptops I have had in the past, the delete key is to the upper right of the backspace key.  However, on my new laptop (Acer Predator Helios 300), they put the home key in that spot.  I use the delete key fairly regularly, but I am not getting used to the weird position of the delete key.  If the button where the delete button should be didn't have a functionality when editing text, I would probably be fine with it.

Is it possible, in Windows 10, to swap the home and delete button?

Comment: I have tried using the keyboard layout creator, but it doesn't let you alter the behavior of these buttons.

Comment: No; What you want is not possible;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible, in Windows 10, to swap the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> button?

The answer here is likely "it depends". As far as I am aware, there is no native mechanism for remapping keys short of editing the registry.

That said, you could try free third-party software such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script:

*ex. swap_keys.ahk*

```
Home::Delete
Delete::Home
```

This script should send <kbd>Delete</kbd> when <kbd>Home</kbd> is pressed and vice versa. One thing to remember is that <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (`Backspace`) and <kbd>Delete</kbd> are two separate keys (in case you run into issues). For reference, here is an [official list of AutoHotkey key names](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) if you need it.

**Caveats**

One thing to consider is that laptop keyboards can be different than standard keyboards from a hardware perspective. Most often this appears with hardware-based `FN` keys (which generally cannot be intercepted/remapped) but may apply more broadly as well. While not a certainty, this could (in theory) pose a problem when using software like AutoHotkey.

Comment: This appears to be working. at least for my laptop.  I just put this in my startup and I am good to go!  Something kind of funny is that pressing ctrl-alt-home and ctrl-alt-delete does the same things with this script.  It also doesn't overwrite the delete and home on my numpad, which is good (as those are where they are supposed to be).

Comment: Note for anyone reading this in the future, that the fn-delete functionality (insert) does not move.  It is still on the original button.

Comment: Good to hear this seems to be working for you. =)